# How to match numbers that are present between ] and [?

Tags: sql, regex, ms-access

How do I match numbers that are present between `]` and `[` (not `[` and `]`)?

**EDIT-1**

In other words, I want to extract those rows where I have a number between `]` and `[`.
My table looks like this...

```
   ID1  id  mycolmn
    1   100 [ab-ee]43[ddhj]
    2   233 [aa-33]49[kl-00]
    3   344 [ss-23][wdsd]
```

And I should get

```
43
49
```

**EDIT-1 ends**

See example file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmmy7pnmkd55tx3/MyDatabase.accdb). I have a column in MyDatabase and I want to extract those rows where there are two digit numbers between `]` and `[`.

Example  `[ab-ee]43[ddhj]` or `[aa-33]49[kl-00]`

The following did not work.

```
SELECT * from myTable where [mycolmn] Like "*\]##\[*"
```

Comment: I deleted my answer after an hour-long google turned up nothing.  Looks like you might need to use an InStr function in a module and parse out the data into a temp table, then filter the temp table.

Comment: @user2174085 I think mine works. I didn't test it yet but I think it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use VBA or SQL.

**VBA**:

```
Function GetCode(MyColumn As String) As String
    Dim RE As New RegExp
    Dim colMatches As MatchCollection
    With RE
        .Pattern = "\]\d\d\["
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = False
        .Multiline = False
        Set colMatches = .Execute(MyColumn)
    End With
    If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        GetCode = Replace(Replace(colMatches(0).Value, "[", ""), "]", "")
    Else
        GetCode = ""
    End If
End Function
```

And you would call it like this:

```
SELECT GetCode([test]) AS MyDigits
FROM test;
```

**If you want a strait SQL solution:**

```
SELECT Mid([test],InStr([test],"]")+1,2) AS MyDigits
FROM test;
```

This assumes that your numbers come after the first ]. If not, it can be modified with more **IIF**, **INSTR**, & **MID** functions to match your pattern. It would be ugly, but it can work.

Comment: Btw, for the VBA solution, you'll need the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yo dawg I heard you like brackets so I put brackets in your brackets so you can escape your brackets

```
  Select * FROM yourTable WHERE MAtch LIKE "*]##[ [ ]*"
```

Comment: I tried it with the same example data and it worked for me. What version of access are you using.

Comment: This doesn't extract the numbers. All it does is show the records that match this pattern.

Comment: You might want to update your question then. "I want to extract those rows where there are......." ask and you shall receive.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Mid([MyColumn],InStr([MyColumn],"]")+1,2) AS MyDigits
 FROM yourTable WHERE [MyColumn] LIKE "*]##[ [ ]*"
```

Please award the check if this answer suits your needs.  That's how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I get the following `MyDigits
row-1) 43
row-2) 49
row-3) [w`

Comment: It works perfectly for me. I have a table with over 100 records and it only returns 2; one with a value of 43 and the other with a value of 49.  Did you double-check the column names?  I just noticed mine used "MyColumn" and yours used "MyColmn".

Comment: Please try with the file I have attached

Comment: Can you save it backwards?  accdb is 2007/2010 and I only have 2003 on my machine.  I need it in mdb format.

Answer (score -1):

You can try PATINDEX:

```
create table TestPatIndex
(
    MyData varchar(100)
)

insert into TestPatIndex select '[ab-ee]43[ddhj]'
insert into TestPatIndex select '[ab-ee]XX[ddhj]'

select SUBSTRING(MyData, PATINDEX ('%][0-9][0-9][[]%', MyData ) + 1, 2)
from TestPatIndex
where isnumeric(SUBSTRING(MyData, PATINDEX ('%][0-9][0-9][[]%', MyData ) + 1, 2)) = 1
```

Here is a [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f4f2/1) to SQL fiddle.

Something like this should work in MS Access:

```
SELECT MyData AS Expr1
FROM TestPatIndex
where MyData like '*][0-9][0-9][[]*'
```

Comment: I thought there will be a straight forward solution. Presently I am drawing data from MsAccess and using `R` to do the filtering. That is working pretty well. I wanted to see if there is any MSAccess syntax